# Resize UIImage to specific bytes

Tags: ios, uiimage, byte

I'm trying to resize UIImage to specific bytes, I've tried with UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someImage, 0.5). But that method is not enough for me, I want to resize to a specific bytes, like 200kb, 1MB, etc ...
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to keep the same image dimensions and find the compression value that gives you the target byte size or do you want a fixed compression and you need to scale the image dimensions until you reach the target byte size?

Comment: Either way, your only option is to iterate and change either the size or the compression until you get the desired byte size.

Comment: My goal must be to keep size and decrease bytes, that should be the best for me. I'm going to try and I'll post about it.

Answer (score 0):

The storage size of an image after compression (e.g. with the suggested `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`) is highly dependent on what's on the image.  If for example the image is solid black it compresses more easily and will result in a small storage size; while an detailed image of house with colorful garden will compress to a much larger size.

If the subject of your images is of identical nature (e.g. same size and type barcodes, microscope images, ...), you could empirically determine the compression factor and stick with that.  If however, the images are of a wide variety of subjects, you'll have to iterate the compressions factor until you reach the desired storage size (within a certain error).

Comment: This is all fine commentary but it really doesn't provide an answer to the question.